# MVC IIS production configuration issue (404)

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7

In my MVC application I have the following mapping:

```
 routes.MapRoute("testRoute", "services/service.js", new {controller = "Home", action = "DoWrokTest"});
```

I want to return a custom javascript from that call. The problem is that on my localmachine from VS debug it works fine ... but on server I get : 404 - File or directory not found.

Do you know which can be the cause? Do I have to configure IIS in a special way to handle all requests through mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have to do some special configuration if your iis 7.0 runs in classic mode see
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs